# Umbraco 7.4.3 Multi domain setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, multilingual, umbraco7

Inside my Umbraco 7.4.3 installation I have one root node, on that node I have multiple domain names specified.

Something like:

```
www.site.local/nl

www.site.local/en

www.site.nl/nl

www.site.nl/en
```

When visiting the www.site.nl/nl site, my website is showing but the urls on the page are showing the www.site.local/nl urls instead of www.site.nl/nl.

What i've tried:

UmbracoSettings.config: **useDomainPrefixes** to true

Inside my application starting:

```
SiteDomainHelper.AddSite("local", "www.site.local"); SiteDomainHelper.AddSite("staging", "www.site.nl");
```

Could someone help me out?

----- Update 2 -----
I tired upgrading my Umbraco installation to see if it was an version related issue.
Upgrading to 7.5.12 After fixing some things, the urls work but the same way as the dit in 7.4.3 (first url in hostname is taken, not the current environment)

Comment: I would recommend posting on our.umbraco.com forums.  Also, Googling those forums is very helpful.

Comment: I already had. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resoled my issues:

- Upgrade to Umbraco 7.5.12
- Fix the obsolate errors (UmbracoContext.Current.Application to ApplicationContext.Current)
- clear the cache
- updated the urlprovider / contentfinder to work with above update

Answer (score 0):

I believe the default domain is the first domain in the Hosts list when you right-click on the root node and set the hosts.